# how to differentiate between location and value of a variable?

Tags: r

I'm searching for the maximum value within a certain range of rows in a CSV file.
I figured out the range, but now that I want to determine the maximum value it just reveals the position of that particular value instead of the actual value.

Initial situation as follows:

First I read the file

```
A <- read.csv(file=data[1], header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

Then I determine the range investigating

```
Duration = as.character (A [16,1])
Duration = as.numeric(strsplit(Duration," ") [[1]][2])

B<- A[which(A==28447)]
```

so these are the target rows:

```
[943] 0.0                                                                                     
[944] 1.8771                                                                                  
[945] 1.2928                                                                                  
[946] 1.7946                                                                                  
[947] 2.3201                                                                                  
[948] 1.8459                                                                                  
[949] 1.5889                                                                                  
[950] 1.3549                                                                                  
[951] 1.2376                                                                                  
[952] 1.1296                                                                                  
[953] 1.0619                                                                                  
[954] 1.0132                                                                                  
[955] 0.9684                                                                                  
[956] 0.93                                                                                    
[957] 0.8976
```

now what I did was:

```
A[(B+1):(B+Duration),1]
```

revealing that:

```
    [1] 0.0    1.8771 1.2928 1.7946 2.3201 1.8459 1.5889 1.3549 1.2376 1.1296 1.0619 1.0132 0.9684 0.93   0.8976
24582 Levels: -0.0 -0.001 -0.0011 -0.0012 -0.0014 -0.0016 -0.0017 -0.0018 -0.0019 -0.0022 -0.0024 -0.0026 -0.0028 -0.003 -0.0033 ... Timesteps: 15
```

If I now go for the `max((B+1):(B+Duration),1)` I get:

`957`

How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`which.max`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/which.min) appropriately<sup>1</sup> returns the *index*. You just want [`max`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/Extremes) instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> `which` in R function names usually refers to indices. For example, `which(A[, 1] > 2)` will return the indices of all elements greater than 2.

Answer (score 1):

`which.max` returns the position of the maximum value in the vector:

```
> A <-  rnorm(10,0,1)
> A
 [1] -1.05831869 -0.20686273 -0.81552863 -0.47213498  0.87199615  0.06288441  0.94777881  0.46776767  1.91153029
[10] -0.59206801
> 
> which.max(A)
[1] 9
```

So, to illustrate this, you could use this to index to the maximum value:

```
> A[which.max(A)]
[1] 1.91153
```

Much simpler though is the `max` function!

```
> max(A)
[1] 1.91153
>
```

If you're getting a not meaningful for factors error you need to convert to numeric first. [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)